# How to access ember helper from controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a ember helper for string internalization. When accessing helper file from ember controller I got `variable` undefined error.

**t-18n.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var i18nData = {
"dashboard": "Dashboard",

};

export function tI18n(params/*, hash*/) {
var value = i18nData[params];
if(value) {
return value;
}
return params;
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(tI18n);
```

**Ember Controller**

```
    import i18n from 'osmizer-client/helpers/t-i18n'
    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
actions: {
get: function() {
i18n.tI18n('dashboard')
}
}
});
```

I got this error "**i18n.default.tI18n is not a function TypeError: i18n.default.tI18n is not a function**".  Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You may be able to access the helper from a controller, but I wouldn't. I would create a service or utility function that performs all of your I18n logic, then have your helper use that service. If you find that you need the helper in places other than a template, it probably shouldn't be a helper. (Just my opinion though.)

Comment: I agree with @GJK, I had the same issue, but conceptually, to have a helper, that are built for templates, to be injected into a controller on further thought seems strange. Thus, you'll find no mention of helpers used in Controllers in [Ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/templates/writing-helpers/).